# ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation doesn't work first time

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to make a transition when a user clicks on an `ImageView` within an item of an adapter with a `RecyclerView`.

The animation works after the first click, but not the first time the user press the `View`.

After the first click, it works perfectly with the same `ImageView`. But if I press another image from another item of the `RecyclerView`, the first time does not work either.

This is the code inside the adapter:

```
holder.ivCommentItemAttachment.setOnClickListener { v ->
    val intent = Intent(context, ImageActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(ImageActivity.EXTRA_IMAGE_URL, imageAttachmentUrl)
    val transitionName = ImageActivity.TRANSITION_IMAGE
    v.transitionName = transitionName
    val options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(context, v, transitionName)
    context.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
}
```

And the activity with the image:

```
class ImageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        const val EXTRA_IMAGE_URL = "image"
        const val TRANSITION_IMAGE = "transitionImage"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image)
        ivImage.transitionName = TRANSITION_IMAGE
        loadCover(this, intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE_URL), ivImage)
        ivImage.setOnClickListener { finishAfterTransition() }
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be that something is consuming the click before it gets to your `ImageView`. Also, because you are using a `RecyclerView` I assume you have more than one image. If it's the case then the transition names should be unique for each one of them, you can achieve that by appending `position` to the transition name.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the code for the transitionName is unique for each item of the `ReciclerView` but the problem persists.

Comment: Just write property `android:transitionName="transition_name"` in the item of viewholder and in the detailed layout.Must work.

Comment: I wrote the `android:transitionName`, but it is exactly the same and I believe it is cleaner programmatically like the documentation comments: on https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity

Comment: `For shared dynamic views that you generate in your code, use the View.setTransitionName() method to specify a common element name in both activities.`

Comment: The problem is on the first click :-(

Comment: @GabrielMoreno : did u find any solution

Comment: No, @DKV... :-(

Comment: I am having the same issue, tried so many none worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just a side note, make sure to delete any `android:transitionName` as well from XML.

I believe the reason for your problem is that you set the transition name in `onClick`. That's why on **first click** the transition doesn't work because the name is not set, and on the **second click** the name is already set (from the **first click**) therefore the transition works. A solution will be to move transition naming from `setOnClickListener` to `onBindViewHolder` so that the transition name is set before the click happens.

**EDIT:**

If not for the above reason or for transition name confusion, then it may be due to the readiness of the `ImageView`s when the transition occurs, in that case you need to postpone the transition until the views are ready.

Try in your `ImageActivity` in `onCreate` to call `supportPostponeEnterTransition()` (because I suppose you are using a support version of the Transition library), and when you load your image into the `ImageView` load it when it's ready. It's easier achieved when using **Picasso** or any other similar library, so your `ImageActivity`s `onCreate` would look something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);
    supportPostponeEnterTransition();

    // inflate you views
    // get your image URL

    Picasso.with(this)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .noFade()
            .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    supportStartPostponedEnterTransition();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    supportStartPostponedEnterTransition();
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: @GabrielMoreno Have you appended the position to the transition name in both `RecyclerView` and `Activity`? It's well illustrated [here](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/mikescamell.com/shared-element-transitions-part-4-recyclerview/amp/).

Comment: I am going to take a look!

Comment: @GabrielMoreno check the edited answer, I added some stuff.

Comment: I have implemented your answer with `Picasso` and `Glide`. It is not a successful solution but I think you have clarified the issue related... The key is the time the library spend to load the image. The second time and then, the image is loaded faster because is cached. But the first one, it has no time to make the transition. If I do the postpone enter transition, the UX is stacked. But I am very happy to know the reason. Thank you very much!

Comment: BTW, I have tried to use the `Application` instance within the call to the library instead of the `Activity` or `Fragment`but it does not work either... :-D

Comment: @GabrielMoreno you are welcome :) I'm glad I helped at least partly :) i have a guess, try to move postpone transition to the activity you are transitioning from, and then in the second activity call `originalActivity.supportStartPostponedEnterTransition`. Also, you have an Activity transitioning to a RecyclerView which is in a Fragment? If it is so, I believe it's much easier having Fragment to Fragment, I have the same case and it works, just my opinion :)

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Maybe the problem is to try to make an animation from the adapter of a RecyclerView within a Fragment and start a new Activity... I'm making it very difficult... :-D

Comment: @GabrielMoreno it well may be :D try the approach with a Fragment :) good luck with that! :)